# Is "I live in a country that speaks the language." correct?

Tags: grammar

I'm learning English. Today I came across this sentence "I live in a country that speaks the language". My question is why the country speaks the language. I would write the sentence like this" I live in a country where people speak the language". Here in the sentence" I live in a country that speaks the language", I know "that" refers to the country. Why does country speak the language? What grammar rule does this sentence follow?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to go to the English Language Learners' site. This is for "advanced" subjects.

Comment: The grammar is quite simple.

Comment: I believe that the issue that you may have with the language is not grammatical, more one of familiarity with a common idiom. As has been noted, you would likely find [ell.se] to be suited to your needs of the moment.

Comment: Actually, the grammar *does* say that it's the country speaking the language—which is ridiculous. Countries don't talk. However, idiomatically, we know what's *meant* by the expression. This is one of those things that, when taken literally, will always confuse people who haven't learned it from context. And, as opposed to the other comments, I don't think that this is a *basic* question. There is a much more complicated answer than is assumed—and one which I can't properly provide.

Comment: I suspect that this question might actually belong at Linguistics, not ELL, since it's really asking about the learning mechanism of those idioms that are either unrelated to, or even contrary to, the words of which they're composed. But it's definitely an advanced subject.